# Restoring to a new database- 'exclusive access could not be obtained'

Tags: sql-server

I am running MSSQL Server 2012 RC 0.

I am using the management studio to create a backup of a database, and then restore it on the SAME server, but with a different database name.

I can create the backup fine, but when I go to restore the backup, I enter the new name of the database that I want it to create (which doesnt exist).

I then get an error saying:

"Restore of database 'newdatabasename' failed....... Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

I know there is plenty on the internet about this, but it is more geared towards restoring over the SAME database.

Which database is it referring to? The old one? I can't see why it would refer to the old database as I am restoring from a full backup file. The new database isn't even created yet so I also can't see why it would be referring to that one.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: When running an experimental release, which is what an RC is, you really need to contact the vendor when you have problems.

Comment: But this is not necessarily a problem with the software- I have a very small amount of knowledge with SQL Server and this is probably a question that would relate to any version

Answer (score 1):

Please execute the following query in SSMS and compare the value of "DatabaseName" column in the output with the database name that you are trying to restore.

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'path of your backup file"
```

I doubt that the backup file contains the database backup of some other database which already exists.

Comment: DatabaseName in the output has the same name as the database that I made a copy of. This is NOT the name of the destination database- the destination database does not yet exist. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use T/SQL to restore the database.  The GUI for doing restores is annoying at best.

```
use master
go
RESTORE DATABASE NewDatabaseNAme from disk='D:\Path\To\Backup\File.bak'
with move 'OldDatabaseFile' to 'e:\Path\To\New\NewDatbaseName.mdf',
move 'OldDatabaseLog' to 'e:\Path\To\New\NewDatabaseName_Log.ldf'
GO
```